# Add row to UITableView Programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to add rows to my `UITableView` programmatically in my chat room code and I can't seem to get it right.  My Code:

```
public override async void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width; 
    UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
    banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MY_TESTAPP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
    banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)width, 73);
    banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
    lblTitle.Text = theSelectedCompany + " Chat Room";
    MyMessages = GetMessages();
    tblMessages.LayoutIfNeeded();
    source.Data = MyMessages;
    tblMessages.Source = source;

    UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
    txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";

    UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
    CGRect ScreenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    float buttonWidth = (float)ScreenBounds.Width / 4;
    btnSendText.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, buttonWidth, 50f);
    btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
    btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);
    btnSendText.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);

    View.Add(banner);
    View.Add(lblTitle);
    View.Add(tblMessages);
    View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
    View.Add(btnSendText);

    View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

    View.AddConstraints(
        banner.AtTopOf(View, 50),
        banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
        banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
        lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
        lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
        tblMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
        tblMessages.AtLeftOf(View),
        tblMessages.WithSameWidth(View),
        tblMessages.Height().EqualTo(height/2),
        txtSendingTextMessage.Below(tblMessages, 10),
        txtSendingTextMessage.WithSameCenterX(tblMessages),
        btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
        btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
    );
        client = new Client(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username, MyUser.Firstname, MyUser.Lastname, theSelectedCompany, theSelectedDept, theSelectedSection, "CHATROOM");
        client.OnMessageReceived += (sender2, message) => AddMessage(message);
        await client.Connect();

        btnSendText.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                client.SendChatMessage(theSelectedCompany, theSelectedDept, theSelectedSection, MyUser.Username, txtSendingTextMessage.Text);
                txtSendingTextMessage.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.LogError("App:MY_TESTAPP (Messenger.cs) - An error occured in the btnSendText.TouchUpInside event, the error is: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Trace: " + Utils.GetExceptionInfo(ex));
            }
        };
}
```

The `AddMessage` code:

```
    public void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        MyMessages.Prepend(message);
        source = new MessageSource();
        source.Data = MyMessages;
        tblMessages.Source = source;
        tblMessages.ReloadData();
        //InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        //{
        tblMessages.ReloadData();
        //});
    }
```

The UITableViewSource Code:

```
public class MessageSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public List<string> Data { get; set; } = new List<string>(); 
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Data.Count;
    }

    public void Add(string Message)
    {
        Data.Prepend(Message);
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = Data[indexPath.Row];

        //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Absolutely everything works as expected, I connect the client to the hub, I retrieve messages from the database, populate the tableview and it all displays fine.  When I send a message, all other users get it, I just can't seem to add any received messages to the tableview.  When messages are received the `AddMessage` code is executed, it's just that the tableview never displays the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, another painful chapter in my iOS coding experience comes to a close.

The issue I was having is that once I created the `MyMessages` list and assigned it to the `MessageSource` instance, I could no longer add anything to it that `MessageSource` would see.  For you `VB` programmers out there (like me), think `ByRef`.  I needed to create a list in `MessageSource` that was by reference to the `MyMessages` list in the `Messages` view controller.  Well as we all know, `ByRef` doesn't exist in the c# class hierarchy but what does is `Interface`, and in this case `IList`, `IList` is an interface to a list of strings, now my code looks like this:

Messages ViewController:

```
IList<string> MyMessages;
public override async void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width; 
    UIImageView banner = new UIImageView();
    banner.Image = UIImage.FromResource(null, "MY_TESTAPP.Resources.drawable.Banner2.jpg");
    banner.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)width, 73);
    banner.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    UILabel lblTitle = new UILabel();
    lblTitle.Text = theSelectedCompany + " Chat Room";
    MyMessages = GetMessages();
    tblMessages.LayoutIfNeeded();
    source.Data = MyMessages;
    tblMessages.Source = source;

    UITextField txtSendingTextMessage = new UITextField(new CGRect(0, width, width, 100));
    txtSendingTextMessage.Placeholder = "Enter Message To Send Here";

    UIButton btnSendText = new UIButton();
    CGRect ScreenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    float buttonWidth = (float)ScreenBounds.Width / 4;
    btnSendText.Frame = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, buttonWidth, 50f);
    btnSendText.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
    btnSendText.SetTitle("Send Text", UIControlState.Normal);
    btnSendText.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);

    View.Add(banner);
    View.Add(lblTitle);
    View.Add(tblMessages);
    View.Add(txtSendingTextMessage);
    View.Add(btnSendText);

    View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

    View.AddConstraints(
        banner.AtTopOf(View, 50),
        banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
        banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),
        lblTitle.Below(banner, 5),
        lblTitle.WithSameCenterX(banner),
        tblMessages.Below(lblTitle, 10),
        tblMessages.AtLeftOf(View),
        tblMessages.WithSameWidth(View),
        tblMessages.Height().EqualTo(height/2),
        txtSendingTextMessage.Below(tblMessages, 10),
        txtSendingTextMessage.WithSameCenterX(tblMessages),
        btnSendText.Below(txtSendingTextMessage, 10),
        btnSendText.WithSameCenterX(txtSendingTextMessage)
    );
        tblMessages.RegisterClassForCellReuse(CellIdentifier);

    client = new Client(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username, MyUser.Firstname, MyUser.Lastname, theSelectedCompany, theSelectedDept, theSelectedSection, "CHATROOM");
    client.OnMessageReceived += (sender2, message) => AddMessage(message);
    await client.Connect();

    btnSendText.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            client.SendChatMessage(theSelectedCompany, theSelectedDept, theSelectedSection, MyUser.Username, txtSendingTextMessage.Text);
            txtSendingTextMessage.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogError("App:MY_TESTAPP (Messenger.cs) - An error occured in the btnSendText.TouchUpInside event, the error is: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Trace: " + Utils.GetExceptionInfo(ex));
        }
    };
}
```

The `MessageSource` code:

```
public class MessageSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public IList<string> Data; 
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return Data.Count;
    }

    public void Add(string Message)
    {
        Data.Prepend(Message);
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = Data[indexPath.Row];

        //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

The `AddMessage` code:

```
public void AddMessage(string message)
{
    MyMessages.Prepend(message);
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        tblMessages.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
    });
}
```

`GetMessages` now returns an `IList<string>` other than that, nothing else changes.  I can send and receive messages and add them to `MyMessages` list like I would any `List` (`MyMessages.Add(message)`).  The difference her is that `Data` in `MessageSource` is now an `Interface` to a list of strings somewhere in memory as is every other reference to `MyMessages`, so now everyone is adding to the same data list.  The chat is ugly as sin and I need to pretty it up and I will, but I wanted to get the functionality to work first.